# bbox works when inputting exact coordinates within module but fails with variable containing identical data

Tags: python, screenshot

I'm having an issue trying to make a screen grab of an area defined by lines in a config file:

The following code:

```
def coordstore():                                 # check line 1 of config file (screencap name)
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    coordstore.x1,coordstore.y1,coordstore.x2,coordstore.y2 = (line[4]).strip(),(line[5]).strip(),(line[6]).strip(),(line[7]).strip()    # note: confusing.  0=line 1, 1=line2 etc.
    coordstore.coords = coordstore.x1+',',coordstore.y1+',',coordstore.x2+',',coordstore.y2
    coordstore.stripped = ' '.join((coordstore.coords))
    print(coordstore.stripped)
    return(coordstore.stripped)
coordstore()

def screenshot():
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab2
    # part of the screen
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        im = ImageGrab2.grab(bbox=(coordstore.stripped))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        im.save('tc.png')
screenshot()
```

prints exactly this value: 10, 20, 100, 300

it then fails with this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file location", line 82, in <module>
    screenshot()

  File "file location", line 80, in screenshot
    im = ImageGrab2.grab(bbox=(coordstore.stripped))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2

  File "PYCHARM\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 67, in grab
    to_file=False, childprocess=childprocess, backend=backend, bbox=bbox)

  File "PYCHARM\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 38, in _grab
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

If I manually replace (bbox=(coordstore.stripped)) with (bbox=(10, 20, 100, 300)) which is literally identical to what the variable prints, the code works perfectly but is not useful for my needs.  What am I not seeing?  Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:

I have tried another approach.

```
def coordstore():                                 # check line 1 of config file (screencap name)
    f=open('config.txt')
    line=f.readlines()
    coordstore.x1 = (line[4]).strip()
    coordstore.y1 = (line[5]).strip()
    coordstore.x2 = (line[6]).strip()
    coordstore.y2 = (line[7]).strip()
    print(coordstore.x1+',', coordstore.y1+',', coordstore.x2+',', coordstore.y2)
    return(coordstore.x1, coordstore.y1, coordstore.x2, coordstore.y2)
coordstore()

def screenshot():
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab2
    # part of the screen
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        im = ImageGrab2.grab(bbox=(coordstore.x1+',', coordstore.y1+',', coordstore.x2+',', coordstore.y2+','))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        im.save('tc.png')
screenshot()
```

This prints

10, 20, 100, 300

but returns the following Traceback errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module location", line 84, in <module>
    screenshot()
  File "module location", line 82, in screenshot
    im = ImageGrab2.grab(bbox=(coordstore.x1+',', coordstore.y1+',', coordstore.x2+',', coordstore.y2+','))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
  File "\PYCHARM\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 67, in grab
    to_file=False, childprocess=childprocess, backend=backend, bbox=bbox)
  File "\PYCHARM\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 42, in _grab
    raise ValueError('bbox y2<=y1')
ValueError: bbox y2<=y1
```

Comment: what is the content and type of `coordstore.stripped`?

Comment: coordstore.stripped prints exactly 10, 20, 100, 300 in terminal.  I'm assuming it is a string but I could be wrong?

Comment: check the type by `type(coordstore.stripped)`

Comment: looks like: class 'str'

Comment: Thanks for sharing type. Please try the with code provided in answer

Comment: new error explain all - you have `y2` lower or equal to `y1` so you have to change it. And don't add `','` to values

Comment: `bbox` needs tuple with numbers  - don't add `','` because you create values which are not numbers. And you could convert strings to integers using `int()` - ie. `bbox=(int(coordstore.x1), int(coordstore.y1), int(coordstore.x2), int(coordstore.y2))`

Comment: as for me you should rather do `x1,y1,x2,y2 = coordstore()` and then `bbox=(x1,y1,x2,y2)` or even `values = coordstore()` and then `bbox = values`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I have tried everything you suggest but the error is the same:

y2<=y1

which is weird because 300 is not < 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in comments the value of `coordstore.stripped` is string. And expected argument by `ImageGrab2.grab` is type of tuple so, first you have to convert it into tuple.

Update the method like this:

```
def screenshot():
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab2
    # part of the screen
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        im = ImageGrab2.grab(bbox=tuple(map(int, coordstore.stripped.split(', '))))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        im.save('tc.png')
```

Comment: I have done this, thanks!  I now receive no errors but 'tc.png' is not being written.  Any thoughts?  Is more info about the code needed?

Comment: Update: After adding this code, print(im) seems to do nothing at all.  Could be related to why tc.png is not writing.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MattW if you have new problem then you should use button "Add question" and create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and explanation.

Comment: If possible, could you look at my edit and let me know if you have thoughts on the new approach?  Thank you so much!  I'm very new to this stuff.